# how to set check box on title of kendo grid angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Below template set check box in grid for every row. but how do i set check box in title of kendo grid. for example below template sets checkbox name  as title. but i want actual checkbox so that when I select it all check boxes in rows are selected.

```
 <kendo-grid-column title="CheckBox">
                    <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                         <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
                    </template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but i am updating the answer, if someone else comes for this.
We have to use kendoGridHeaderTemplate for setting checkbox at header.
Example:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Select" width="30">
                <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>
                  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="false" />
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate>
                  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="false" />
                </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```